# Ubuntu 12.0.4.3 Dektop Operating System

Tags: installation

hello sir i have downloaded the Ubuntu setup file in compressed format,now i would like to boot it from pen drive,without affecting the existing operating system how can i do it.please provide me some instructions.o

Comment: Which compressed format did you download and from where?

Answer (score 0):

To run Ubuntu from a USB stick, the first thing you need to do is insert a USB stick with at least 2GB of free space into your PC.

The easiest way to put Ubuntu onto your stick is to use the USB installer provided at pendrivelinux.com. You’ll need to [download and install](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) and follow the instructions.

1. Select Ubuntu Desktop Edition from the dropdown list.
2. Click 'Browse' and open the downloaded ISO file.
3. Choose the USB drive and click 'Create'.

Now ensure that you can boot from USB..

make the necessary edits in your bios to ensure that...

now you can boot and try...

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Open your Iso file with power iso.
In the tools , select the option "make bootable USB", this will make your USB drive a BOOTABLE USB. 
Restarting your lappy should prompt you with Ubuntu Installation